# Can`t download with yum on Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I installed Linux CentOS on a virtualbox. The internet connection is thru proxy but I understood I have to modifiy resolv.conf. I added the proxy, username and password and then I tested with the command : yum repolist and I get this :

```
Loaded plugins: fastesmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14:curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Loading mirror speed from cached hostfile 
Loading mirror speed from cached hostfile 
Loading mirror speed from cached hostfile 
repo id                      repo name
base/7/x86_64               CentOS -7- base
extras/7/x86_64             CentOS -7- extras
updates/7/x86_64            CentOS -7- updates
repolist: 0
```

What does this error mean ? And what do I have to do to download with yum.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like yum can't access the internet through the proxy. As far as I know yum has it's own config file where you can set a proxy. It's located at “/etc/yum.conf“ and should look something like this:

```
[main]
...
proxy=http://<Proxy-Server-IP-Address>:<Proxy_Port>
proxy_username=<Proxy-User-Name>
proxy_password=<Proxy-Password> 
...
```

If that doesn't work then the problem must be related to the vm networking I guess